# R: Counting occurrences in each column and replacing that column's value with the count (SQL?)

Tags: r, data-manipulation, sqldf

Here is an example of the original data:

```
ID        Test1    Test2       Test3      Test4

1          0         0          NA         1.2

1          0         NA         NA         3.0 

1          NA        NA         NA          0 

2          0         0          0           0

2          0         0          NA          NA
```

I want to count how many non-NA occurrences (so including 0) for each ID and replace that columns value with that number.  Producing this:

```
ID        Test1    Test2       Test3      Test4

1           2        1          NA          3

2           2        2          1           1
```

I don't know if I need to use the sqldf package in R.  I tried coercing the data frame to a data table and reshaping it but it did not work.

df <- x %>% melt(idvars='ID')

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do a group by `sum` on the logical vector

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(na_if(sum(!is.na(.)), 0)))
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#     ID Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     2     1    NA     3
#2     2     2     2     1     1
```

---

Or use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(.~ ID, df1, FUN = function(x) sum(!is.na(x)), na.action = NULL)
```

Or with `rowsum`

```
rowsum(+(!is.na(df1[-1])), df1$ID)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Test1 = c(0L, 0L, 
NA, 0L, 0L), Test2 = c(0L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L), Test3 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, 0L, NA), Test4 = c(1.2, 3, 0, 0, NA)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Below we discuss solutions using the two packages mentioned in the question.

**1) sqldf** To use the sqldf package referenced in the question using the input defined reproducibly in the Note at the end:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select ID, 
              nullif(count(Test1), 0) Test1,
              nullif(count(Test2), 0) Test2,
              nullif(count(Test3), 0) Test3,
              nullif(count(Test4), 0) Test4
       from DF
       group by ID")
```

giving:

```
  ID Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4
1  1     2     1    NA     3
2  2     2     2     1     1
```

`nullif(count(test1), 0)` can be shortened to just `count(test1)` if it is ok to report a 0 for an ID that is all NA and similarly for the other test* columns.

**1a)** If in reality there are many columns, not just 4, or you don't like repeating part of the `select` we can build up the string and then insert it like this:

```
testNames <- names(DF)[-1]
select <- toString(sprintf("nullif(count(%s), 0) %s", testNames, testNames))

library(sqldf)
fn$sqldf("select ID, $select
       from DF
       group by ID")
```

Add the `verbose = TRUE` argument to the `sqldf` call to see that the same string is actually sent to the back end.

If it is ok to report 0 instead of NA then we could simplify the `select <- ...` to:

```
select <- toString(sprintf("count(%s) %s", testNames, testNames))
```

**2) reshape2** To use `melt` as in the code attempt in the question:

```
library(magrittr)
library(reshape2)

count <- function(x) if (all(is.na(x))) NA_integer_ else sum(!is.na(x))

DF %>% 
  melt(id.vars = "ID") %>% 
  dcast(ID ~ variable, count)
```

If it is OK to report 0 for any ID that is all NA then count could be simplified to:

```
count <- function(x) sum(!is.na(x))
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "ID        Test1    Test2       Test3      Test4
1          0         0          NA         1.2
1          0         NA         NA         3.0 
1          NA        NA         NA          0 
2          0         0          0           0
2          0         0          NA          NA"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```